# Which software do I need to make a single video out of few pics of different resolution and videos of different resolution

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

We had a get-together party. I'm the most technically sound person in my group. I collected pictures & videos from all the friends who attended that party. Because, not all are taken using same camera. These pictures & videos are of **different resolutions**.

Now, I want to group all of them in to a single video and add some music etc. How can I achieve it? Which software would be better suited for my purpose?

**EDIT:** I'm on windows, my main issue is **different resolutions**. Some pics & videos are 640*480. And some are in the orders of 2400*1800. Now, I've to combine them to make a single video.

Comment: Hi @claws. What Operating System are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Two software packages come to mind:  Adobe Premiere Elements, and Sony Vegas.  There are probably a bunch of others, but I've used both and they are easy to use.  You should be able to resize the videos in both programs to match the resolution you want.

Comment: I've used Premier Elements before, and doing this sort of thing involved dragging a boatload of pictures into the timeline. It took a while to sort everything out, but it created the video perfectly without any further interaction.

Comment: Actually I tried using Adobe Premiere, I liked it but there is one issue with that. I'm making a video of resolution say (1024*768) then all the images that are of higher resolution than this are being *trimmed* (rather than scaled) to this resolution.